# Systemd service won't start after reboot

Tags: python, ubuntu, systemd

I everyone,

I have a issue with my service. I want to start a python script at boot (it takes more or less 20 seconds to complete this script) and I want to execute it every 2 minutes. So I create this service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Set and check time and date of the board

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=120
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/dev/Configuration-Folder/daemons/configureTimeScript.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I launch the script with "sudo python /home/dev/Configuration-Folder/daemons/configureTimeScript.py"  it works very well but when I restart Ubuntu (16.04), the service won't start and shows me that it is inactive (dead)...

Can you give me some tips to solve this issue?

Thank you

**Update 1**
When I want to manually start the service with "sudo systemctl start setDateTime.service" the service start as expected and stay in "active (running)", which is good

**Update 2**
I enabled the service and restart Ubuntu but nothung changed

Comment: When you've created the service file have you then enabled it so that it is set to start on boot? So ```systemctrl enable your-service-name-here``` If not it is probably just that

Have you also tried starting the service to make sure that it's able to run as a deamon?

Comment: Yes I enabled it and I also tried to start it and by starting it manually, it works

Answer (score 3):

I've written an example systemd service that executes a Python script that runs every 10 seconds.

Python script at `/opt/hello.py`:

```
#!/bin/env python3

import os

os.system("echo 'Hello' > /home/telmo/Desktop/hello.txt")
```

Note the shebang in the beginning of the file, I also made the script executable with `chmod +x /opt/hello.py`.
With these two steps done I can now call the script from command line simply as `/opt/hello.py`.

Then I created the service unit file (`hello.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=My Python Script

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/hello.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And moved it to the correct folder with `sudo mv hello.service /etc/systemd/system`.

With that done I just had to enable the service and start it for the first time:

```
sudo systemctl enable hello
sudo systemctl start hello
```

Now a `hello.txt` is created in my user's desktop every 10 seconds. Try deleting it and it will be generated again. The behavior will persist through system reboots since we enabled the service.

Comment: I copy/paste your service and chenged the ExecStart path (of course) but it still remain "inactive (dead)" after thre reload-daemon and restart

Comment: I assume you have enabled the service as well (`sudo systemctl enable SERVICE_NAME`). Does it work with my Python script? If it does there probably is something in your script preventing it from working properly.

Comment: It is realy strange because when I copy your python, paste it inside /opt/, the script stop because of a faillure... "/opt/hello.py: No such file or directory" and if I verified if the script was at the right place and I found it so I am 100% sure that the file exist

Comment: UPDATE: After the reboot, even if the path is not good (according to journalctl), the service is started...

Comment: Have you confirmed you can run the script from the command line with `/opt/hello.py`?